# Word2Vec compare vectors from different models with different sizes

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, gensim, word2vec

I have trained several word2vec models using gensim for different languages, but the `size` is different for each of them.

vectors are obtained like this:

```
vec_sp = word_vectors_sp.get_vector("uno")
```

How to use `vec_sp` as input for different model with different vector size:

```
word_vectors_en.most_similar(positive=[vec_sp], topn=1)
```

to obtain the corresponding word in the second model

Comment: pad the smaller vector with zeros is one obvious suggestion that jumps to mind. Although semantically comparing vectors from different models doesn't make much sense

Comment: I agree with @cs95, comparing vectors from different models doesn't make any sense. These models are trained to represent the distributional similarity between words, encoded by the cosine of the angle between vectors.

You can imagine rotating all vectors of a model by some degrees, thereby constructing a new model. Both models would enocode the exact same distributional similarity, but the most similar vector in the 2. model of a vector in the 1. model would only be dependent on the amount of rotation you applied. For your task, I suggest researching cross lingual word embeddings.

Comment: Thank you both for the replies, I also thought the same but was hoping that there is still some way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

If the models were trained separately, even if they had the same number of dimensions, the vectors wouldn't be meaningfully comparable.

It is only the interleaved training tug-of-war, between words that are being learned for the same model from mixes of varied contexts, that causes their end-positions to have meaningful distances.

For example, even if both models are for the same language, and include many similar text examples, the word 'apple' in one, and the word 'apple' in another, could wind up in arbitrarily different final positions – thanks to both random initialization & lots of randomization use during the algorithm's operation. The distance/direction between these positions is essentially meaningless. The only consistency that should be expected is that from training material of roughly similar quality/sufficiency, the word's neighbors should be very similar.

If two models do contain many of the *same* words, there is a possibility to separately learn a "translation" between the two spaces, in a separate optimization process. It takes a large number of shared anchor words, learns a mathematical transformation that does a fair job of moving words from one coordinate space to another, and then that same transformation can be applied to words that aren't in both models.

This technique has had some success in suggesting similar words in a another language in machine translation, and there's some example implementing code in the `gensim` library's `TranslationMatrix` class:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/translation_matrix.html

(It's usually used between models of the same dimensionality but it might work more generally.)

Comment: yes i agree with Radim... sections 3 and 4 of this paper describe the approach... https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.4168.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The systematic approach to the problem of being able to compare across *n* different embedded vector spaces with different dimensions *d_1,...d_n* is to reduce the dimensionality of the vectors in each space to a value *m* where *m* < min(d_1,...d_n).

There are many ways of doing it. By [Johnson Lindenstrauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma), you could do it by applying **random projections** in each space separately, i.e.,
choose a random projection matrix Ri of size *m x d_i* for each set of vectors *Xi_{d_i} x N* (assuming each space has N vectors) and then compute

Xi' _{m x N} = Ri _{m x d_i} x Xi _{d_i x N} (dimensions of the matrix are shown alongside).

After applying this transformation for each space, you will end up with i such spaces... the dimension of each will be *m*, which means that you will be able to compute dot products *between* them.

One more approach for dimensionality reduction is to use **PCA**. Python's sklearn provides implementations for both [random projections](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/random_projection.html) and [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html).

In terms of a concrete example, if you have two vector spaces of 100 and 200 dimensions each with 100,000 vectors then reduce each to 20 dimensions (arbitrarily chosen) by PCA or random projection. You would then be able to compare these 20 dimensional vectors by computing distances or inner products.

Comment: I will give this a try

Comment: The results I am getting are meaningless. Basically I am trying to translate word from one language to another and the results are totatlly unrelated. Probably with better training and data things might work better

Comment: If you want to translate words from one language to another, you need a small seed set of parallel words which could be used to train a transformation from one language to another... read sections 3 and 4 of this paper... https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.4168.pdf